# MYSQL invalid group function

Tags: mysql

I have an error called 'Invalid use of group function' when I am rendering this query

```
SELECT d.emp_id 'Employee ID'
     , concat(d.fname,' ',d.lname) 'Employee Name'
     , d.rate 'Rate'
     , d.hourly_rate 'Hourly Rate'
     , a.date 'Date'
     , MIN(a.time_in) 'Time In'
     , MAX(a.time_out) 'Time Out'
     , subtime(MAX(a.time_out),MIN(a.time_in))  'HoursRendered'
     ,
    cast(time_to_sec(subtime(MAX(a.time_out),MIN(a.time_in))) / (60 * 60) as decimal(10, 2)) 'Hours Rendereds'
     ,
    sum(d.Hourly_Rate * cast(time_to_sec(subtime(MAX(a.time_out),MIN(a.time_in))) / (60 * 60) as decimal(10, 2))) 'Payroll'
      FROM employee_details d
      JOIN emp_attendance a
        ON d.emp_id = a.emp_id
     where a.emp_id = 17
     Group 
        by a.emp_id
         , a.date
```

below is the sample data when I removed the `min` and `max` from `Payroll` query

```
Employee ID Employee Name         Rate  Hourly Rate Date        Time In  Time Out Hours Rendered    Hours Rendereds Payroll
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-02  20:57:50 22:37:01 01:39:11           1.65           993.35
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-03  19:55:13 22:19:24 02:24:11           2.40           0
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-05  20:25:30 21:20:49 00:55:19           0.92           3741.07
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-06  08:39:56 08:47:31 00:07:35           0.13           70.71
```

As you can see in column 1, the payroll is **993.35** instead of **555.60** , what happens there is that all of the repetitive `time_in` and `time_out` of that employee on that particular date is being executed in the query. That's why I only want to get the *First Time In* and *Last Time Out* of that particular employee.

Here is the sample data where the value **993.35** comes from.

```
Employee ID Employee Name         Rate  Hourly Rate Date        Time In  Time Out Hours Rendered    Hours Rendereds Payroll
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-02  20:57:50 22:37:01 01:39:11           1.65           555.60
17          John Doe              55000 336.73      2021-02-02  21:18:50 22:37:01 01:18:11           1.30           437.75

Thanks
```

Comment: You got one aggregation within another, you cannot do that. What are you trying to do with that `sum` column? Do you perhaps want `sum(employee_details.Hourly_Rate) * cast...` i.e. close the `sum` then do the multiplication by `min` etc

Comment: i want to multiply the hourly rate to the converted decimal number of the `cast(time_to_sec(subtime(MAX(emp_attendance.time_out),MIN(emp_attendance.time_in))) / (60 * 60) as decimal(10, 2))`

Comment: Given `emp_attendance.emp_id` is fixed to 17 what if you removed `emp_attendance.emp_id`  from `GROUP BY`? Could you fetch employee details in a separate query?

Comment: `emp_attendace.emp_id` isn’t always fixed, i just put 17 there to just select particular rather than all

Comment: @Strawberry I edited my question and gave sample data, thanks for pointing me out that questions.

Comment: I refer you again to the accepted answer at the linked question.